# Vertical Text - Bitmap Font Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

[image: vertical]
How can I achieve this kind of rotation or vertical text using Bitmap Font?

I already used Matrix but didn't get the result same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw each letter in a new line using `\n`

```
drawMultiLine(Batch batch, java.lang.CharSequence str, float x, float y)
```

Draws a string, which may contain newlines (`\n`), at the specified position.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How can I rotate each line? Should I use Matrix? Can you provide code samples.

Comment: @xitnesscomplex there is no rotation. This answer suggests to draw each letter in a new line without rotation